# How can Reload the image from PAGES in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to display(load) the Image from WINDOWS application into PAGES but I'm not able to reload it by using buttons of other WINDOWS.

**This is the part where i want to reload my images in PAGES**

```
<Border x:Name="border" ClipToBounds="True" Background="#FFBBB1B1">
     
    <Image x:Name="imagesScroll" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"   Stretch="Fill" >
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>

</Border>
```

**This is the part of frame in WINDOWS**

```
<Frame  x:Name="Frame_mainWindow"  Source="/xyz.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Visible"\>
</Frame>
```

**This is the part of button when i click this button then image will load from the other folder or file in WINDOWS**

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\ABC\\ABC\\XYZ\\XYZ";
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Image Files (*.png; .jpg; .jpeg; .gif; .bmp)|*.png;.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.bmp|All files (*.*)|*.*";

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        string imagePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
        MessageBox.Show(imagePath ) ;
        ABC mainWindow = ABC.Instance;
    }
}
```

**This is the part the with set the path of image which i got the image from the folder**

```
public void MainLoadImage(string imagePath)
{
    try
    {
        imagesScroll.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Got an Exception loading image: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me some help to solve this problem?